# I don't have "add reference" in my project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

and I have a problem, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgzH4.png)

I wanted to add a assembly reference but I don't have a button, only "Add Project reference". How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not tech support. Your question is not about writing code, but about *a program that you are using* (your IDE). Please try https://superuser.com.

Comment: You have a .NET Core / .NET 5 project. You should add references to libraries via NuGet, or if you have local libraries from DLLs you can use "Add Project Reference". Beyond that your issue isn't entirely clear?

Comment: @Karl IDE questions are on-topic. Check the tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Just click Add Project Reference and go to the Assemblies tab to browse to the DLL you want to reference.

Docs: [How to: Add or remove references by using the Reference Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019).

If Assemblies isn't shown, then your project type doesn't support assembly references.

Comment: thank you i added it's via nugets, sorry if my questions stupid, i'm absolutely new in programming

Comment: Don’t you have the option of ‘Manage Nuget packages‘? This option is used to add nugets.